# How could I fix this white space replacement code?

Tags: jquery, categories, whitespace, blogs, non-breaking-characters

I've replaced all white spaces with non-breaking space in categories with the jquery below. However, it doesn't seem to work for categories found in blog pages. I did a site inspect and found that the class for each category is ".blog-item-category-wrapper". Have tried this and adjacent classes but none seem to work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".blog-item-category-wrapper").each(function() { // select all elements with class "categories" and loop through them
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\s/g,'&nbsp;')); // replace all white spaces with nbsp
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is the webpage in question: https://kazoo-cheetah-9f28.squarespace.com/print/title-zero-ending-the-infinite-loop-of-classifications-for-broadband-via-a-technology-agnostic-definition. The categories are right underneath the blog post title.

Thanks so much for your help with this.

Comment: The problem is that your regexp matches inside HTML tags, so `<a href="...">` becomes `<a&nbsp;href="...">`. So you're breaking the HTML.

Comment: Why don't you just set the CSS to `white-space: pre`?